# App Crashing when swipping the HorizontalPagerIndicator in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

I am using HorizontalPagerIndicator as below:

```
item {
                    Box {
                        HorizontalPager(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(200.dp),
                            count = pages.size,
                            state = pagerState,
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
                        ) { position ->
                            ImagesScreen(media = pages[position])
                            HorizontalPagerIndicator(
                                pagerState = pagerState,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .align(
                                        Alignment.BottomCenter
                                    )
                                    .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                            )

                        }

                    }
                }
```

This is inside LazyColumn. I am getting crash log as below when scrolling the HorizontalPager.

```
Process: om.namostate.jetpackroom, PID: 10655
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Check failed.
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$precompose$1.dispose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:566)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutPrefetcher.cancelScheduledPrefetch(LazyLayoutPrefetcher.android.kt:274)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutPrefetchPolicy.cancelScheduledPrefetch(LazyLayoutPrefetchPolicy.kt:42)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState.notifyPrefetch(LazyListState.kt:305)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState.onScroll$foundation_release(LazyListState.kt:266)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState$scrollableState$1.invoke(LazyListState.kt:150)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState$scrollableState$1.invoke(LazyListState.kt:150)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.DefaultScrollableState$scrollScope$1.scrollBy(ScrollableState.kt:134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.ScrollingLogic.dispatchScroll-f0eR0lY(Scrollable.kt:314)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.ScrollDraggableState.dragBy-Uv8p0NA(Scrollable.kt:389)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.DraggableKt$draggable$9$2$2.invokeSuspend(Draggable.kt:244)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:68)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1648)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1659)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1129)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1045)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1622)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
```

What might be the reason for the crash?

Comment: Your code indicates that you are using  `HorizontalPager` out of the Accompanist library. The `HorizontalPager` has already been integrated into [official Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/package-summary#HorizontalPager), so I would suggest that you migrate it first and then check again whether the issue persists. Read [here](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#migration) how to migrate. Then please edit your post and update your code.

Answer (score 0):

[`HorizontalPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/package-summary#HorizontalPager) has been moved from Accompanist to the official Jetpack Compose. Please try to [migrate](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#migration) it first and see if that already resolves the issue:

1. Make sure you are using Compose 1.4.0+ before attempting to migrate to `androidx.compose.foundation.pager`.
2. Change `com.google.accompanist.pager.HorizontalPager` to `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager`
3. Change `count` variable to `pageCount`.
4. Change `itemSpacing` parameter to `pageSpacing`.
5. Change any usages of `rememberPagerState()` to `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.rememberPagerState()`
6. Run your changes on device and check to see if there are any differences.